# Request pdb files from remote server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I build the boost library and got a lot of pdb files. 
And I want to get this pdb files from my remote server.
I made simple fileserver on Tornado(python) and setting up sources for pdb files in visual studio 2015.

Requests for microsoft's pdb files like this come to my server.

```
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8000', method='GET', 
    uri='/sechost.pdb/62E740599FAE040A3AB9017E347BC2831/sechost.pdb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 'User-Agent': 'Microsoft-Symbol-Server/10.0.10150.9', 'Host': 'localhost:8000', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
        sechost.pdb/62E740599FAE040A3AB9017E347BC2831/sechost.pdb
```

Requests for boost pdb files aren't come to server. 
My simple test program:

```
boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)     
       std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

boost::chrono::duration<double> sec = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
```

I think that Visual Studio does not send requests for boost pdb files.
But why?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio already has a feature to do this, no need to implement it yourself. Look up Microsoft symbol server, you can then point any workstations at the server in the VS settings under Tools->Options then Debugging->Symbols.

Comment: The main problem that visual studio doesnt sent requests for boost pdb files. The realisation of symbol server isn't important.